# RegEx - Looking for emails inside of a log file

Tags: regex, parsing

I am looking for a regular expression that will test for matches against a string such as:

mxtreme1.log:May 12 07:00:00 10.1.1.175 postfix/cleanup[48145]: C2C9FFA730: fullname=, **sender=*LOGINNAME*@company.com**, from=LOGINNAME@company.com, recip=LOGINNAME@company.com, prior=, as_score=0, as_strategy=M, code=W, actions=FFFFFFFFFFFTFFFFFFFFFF, analysis=F000FFF000TTT000F000TFT000000TTSS3000059900033-F1F-FF00000000F000FFF000000000000F1FFF000F000

where the entire part in bold is a match, but LOGINNAME can be any number of random characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
sender=[^@]+@company\.com
```

(You were explicitly stating that only the *LOGINNAME* part would be variable.)

Answer (score 2):

To test all of the above solutions, i personally love using 'The Regex Coach'

Just google for that string and its a freeware that has served me well.

PS: I dont own nor have any sort of vested interest in the product or the team that built it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that a comma isn't valid inside of an email address, so as long as it always has the comma afterwards, you should be able to get it with:

```
/(sender=[^,]+?),/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for email addresses according to [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).

It's surprisingly long, but email addresses can be more complex than you may expect.

Just prefix it with `/sender\s*=\s*/` to only get sender emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

But look at [this post](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to get why RegEx and emails address are problematic.

Also this to add the SENDER=:

```
^[\w]+=[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```